# Does python close the file after it comes out?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I tired two code examples , one with close and the other with out close, strace says both code has called .close()

is it safe to understand python3.6 does an automatic close:

Eg1: 
the lines in the file is :

```
f = open('./myConfig.cfg')
jsonda = json.loads(f.read())
```

The corresponding strace o/p is

```
open("./myConfig.cfg", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=693, ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7ffe829a80a0)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7ffe829a8040)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=693, ...}) = 0
read(3, "{\n  \"osns\" : [\n    {\n      \"fabr"..., 694) = 693
read(3, "", 1)                          = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f57b2bc1390}, {0x442160, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f57b2bc1390}, 8) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
sigaltstack(NULL, {ss_sp=0x1f2b0b0, ss_flags=0, ss_size=8192}) = 0
sigaltstack({ss_sp=NULL, ss_flags=SS_DISABLE, ss_size=0}, NULL) = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

---

Similarly  in the second file:

```
f = open('./myConfig.cfg')
jsonda = json.loads(f.read())
f.close()
```

The corresponding strace o/p is

```
open("./myConfig.cfg", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=693, ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7fff2e3f27c0)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7fff2e3f2760)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=693, ...}) = 0
read(3, "{\n  \"osns\" : [\n    {\n      \"fabr"..., 694) = 693
read(3, "", 1)                          = 0
close(3)                                = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f4f52f6d390}, {0x442160, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7f4f52f6d390}, 8) = 0
sigaltstack(NULL, {ss_sp=0x15130b0, ss_flags=0, ss_size=8192}) = 0
sigaltstack({ss_sp=NULL, ss_flags=SS_DISABLE, ss_size=0}, NULL) = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: Just use `with open()`?

Comment: @ajax_velu, python does not close the file automatically. In short Garbage collector will close file when it destroys file object.

Comment: I would recommend closing the file after you're done with it.  If only for the sake of good practice.

Comment: If the file object goes out of scope then python will close it.  If I modify your first example to:
jsonda = json.loads(open('./myConfig.cfg').read()) then the file object goes out of scope right away and there is nothing to call close() on.

Answer (score 1):

See this part of documentation [Reading and writing files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) its fully answers your question, so *"read the docs"*. I will provide a quote from there:

> If you’re not using the `with` keyword, then you should call `f.close()`
>   to close the file and immediately free up any system resources used by
>   it. If you don’t explicitly close a file, **Python’s garbage collector
>   will eventually destroy the object and close the open file for you,
>   but the file may stay open for a while.** Another risk is that different
>   Python implementations will do this clean-up at different times.

Another part of the same section advocates to use `with` block, because in this case it is guaranteed to properly release the resources even if an exception is raised at some point (I think except `SystemError`):

> It is good practice to use the `with` keyword when dealing with file
>   objects. The advantage is that the file is properly closed after its
>   suite finishes, even if an exception is raised at some point. Using
>   with is also much shorter than writing equivalent `try-finally` blocks.

Eventually to answer your question - yes it is safe to assume that Python does an automatic close, but it is not safe to implicitly rely on.